did mahadev disrespect mata parvati?
So my question is ...when I was reading shiva purana edited by J.L Shastri I found this in section 2.4 rudra-samhita (kumara-khanda), does this mean shiv/Mahadev disrespected his wife? I have very little knowledge of all this and this is my first time reading something like this , so be kind.

But if we are going to be humble, there is likely to be a rumour: “Śiva is subservient to his wife.” O Gaṇas, this is certainly derogatory to me.

How can a woman be obdurate especially with her husband? Pārvatī will certainly derive the fruit of what she has done.


https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226134.html

Incidents like this are their playful līlā. No real separation or disrespect can even be imagined between the parents of the universe!
From Śivapurāṇa, Rudrasaṃhitā (2), Satīkhaṇḍa, Chapter 25:

इत्थं शिवाशिवकथां वदन्ति मुनयो मुने ।
किल केचिदविद्वांसो वियोगश्च कथं तयोः ॥

"But O sage, some ignorant Pandits thus narrate the story of Śivā and Śiva and their separation. But how can there be a real separation between the two?"

शिवाशिवचरित्रं को जानाति परमार्थतः ।
स्वेच्छया क्रीडतस्तो हि चरितं कुरुतस्सदा ॥

"Who knows the true life and conduct of Śivā and Śiva. They sport about of their own accord and make their own lives for ever."

वागर्थाविव संपृक्तौ सदा खलु सतीशिवौ ।
तयोर्वियोगस्संभाव्यस्संभवेदिच्छया तयोः ॥

"Śatī and Śiva are united together like words and their meanings. Only if they wish, can their separation be even imagined."

But what do these leela's convey? what is the meaning of these words that mahadev said to mata parvati , they are harsh ones . and also I can't find anything in shiv puran from mata's perspective . can you suggest which authentic book should I read to gain more knowledge about mahadev and adi shkti's gatha. Also I'm deeply influenced by the tv series 'DEVO KE DEV MAHADEV' and this one set my standard about these two (shiv-parvati)too high .(not complaining).
